# Why can I check to see if a Struct is equal to null?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, struct, null, compiler-warnings

Unity has a struct [Color](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color.html).  It's default value is [Color.white](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Color-white.html).  So to check if it is its default value, I can use `myColor == default(Color)` or `myColor == Color.white`.

However, I came across some code that checks if `myColor == null`.  The code compiles, and Visual Studio gives the suggestion to turn it into `false`.  I assume this is because a Color cannot be null.  This applies to all Unity structs I have seen, such as Vectors as well.

If I use a regular struct in C#, it gives me the suggestion, but also fails to compile.

```
Color myColor = new Color();
bool defaultColor = myColor == null; //Compiles

MyStruct myStruct = new MyStruct();
bool defaultStruct = myStruct == null; //Does not compile
```

Why do Unity Structs allow null checks?  Why does this compile?

Comment: To paraphrase the duplicate's answer, because the `Color` type has a overloaded `==` operator, the compiler "lifts" an overloaded `==` operator for `Nullalbe<Color>`, lifts both the `Color` and the null literal to `Nullable<Color>` and uses that operator.

Comment: Whoever deleted their answer, why?  That was a useful answer specific to my case, showing why it was a duplicate.  The reference to the source code also helped:  https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/UnityCsReference/blob/54dd67f09e090b1ad5ba1f55886f327106406b0c/Runtime/Export/Color.cs#L95

Comment: It compiles because the struc Color overloads the == operator. The same thing happens with the DateTime struct. If you overload the == and != operators in MyStruct, it will compile

Comment: Also see Eric Lippert's comment to his accepted answer to the marked duplicate question: *"User-defined value types which have a user-defined equality operator defined also by default have a lifted user-defined equality operator generated for them. The lifted user-defined equality operator is applicable for the reason you state: all value types are implicitly convertible to their corresponding nullable type, as is the null literal. It is not the case that a user-defined value type that lacks a user-defined comparison operator is comparable to the null literal."*

Comment: @Evorlor I think it was deleted because it did not fully answer the question and because a duplicate was found. I have voted to undelete it because it does give the reason that the duplicate answer applies.

Comment: Structs cannot be nullable, instead you can remplace struct by class which is nullable.